# Bash several and in if

Tags: bash, if-statement

Hi I have a csv file with dates like this which I want to parse with bash and check against todays date.

```
12-Jan-2015
```

Checking only day and month works good

```
  DAT=$(date '+%d %b %Y')
  DAY=${DAT:0:2}
  MON=$(echo ${DAT:3:3} | awk '{print toupper("$0");}')
  YEAR=${DAT:6:5}

  while IFS=",-" read name day month year
    do
        day=$(printf "%02d\n" "$day")
        month=$(echo "$month" |  awk '{print toupper($0);}')
        year=$(printf "%04d\n" "$year")
          if [ "$day" -eq "$DAY" ] && [ "$month" = "$MON" ]; then
            echo "$name";
          fi
    done < $SNAPDB > $SNAPTMPDB
```

but when I try to also check the year

```
if [ "$day" -eq "$DAY" ] && [ "$month" = "$MON" ] && [ "$year" -eq "$YEAR" ]; then
```

Script ends with an error: **line 119:  2015: command not found**

I´ve by now tried several writings like [[ … ]] -a and so on. but nothing did work.

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `-a` for 'and' and `-o` for 'or'. From the documentation: http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_07_01.html (look specifically at Table 7-2)

**Updated from comments**:

Use double brackets and parentheses:

```
if ( [[ "$day" -eq "$DAY" ]] && [[ "$month" = "$MON" ]] && [[ "$year" -eq "$YEAR" ]] ); then`
```

Comment: wow that was fast! I´ve tried this already if [ "$day" -eq "$DAY" ] -a [ "$month" = "$MON" ] -a [ "$year" -eq "$YEAR" ]; then but unfortunately this ends with line 118: [: missing `]' line 119:  2015: command not found

Comment: Try using parentheses and double brackets... like: `if ( [[ "$day" -eq "$DAY" ]] -a [[ "$month" = "$MON" ]] -a [[ "$year" -eq "$YEAR" ]] ); then` . Theoretically, with that syntax, you could use `&&` also. I don't have access to a bash shell to try right now. Double brackets are the recommended (non-POSIX) syntax to check for string conditions (and double parentheses for numeric checks)

Comment: YES! -a ended in an error but && worked! thanks a million! if ( [[ "$day" -eq "$DAY" ]] && [[ "$month" = "$MON" ]] && [[ "$year" -eq "$YEAR" ]] ); then

Comment: Great! Sorry I couldn't be more explicit on my answer but I don't have a linux box handy right now :-)

Comment: I'll edit the answer so it reflects the actual answer in the comments